# NSURLSession in For Loop to Download Image Data then add to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

My application has a UITableView with a cell that contains a UICollectionView subview (not reused). The collectionView's cells have a single UIImageView to hold a picture. I am trying to download all of the images at once, store them in an array, and then display the contents of the array in the collectionView cell **once the images are all downloaded**. In ObjC I have done this many times using `NSURLConnection` but I am trying to use Swift and `NSURLConnection` to achieve this but I'm running into what I believe may either be concurrency or semantics issues. Maybe one of you guys could point me in the right direction because I feel like I'm spending too much time on this.

In my UITableView's cell subclass that contains the collectionView I am calling

```
func downloadPhotosWithURLs(urls: [String]) {

    var imagesMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for url in urls {

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { (data, repsonse, err) -> Void in

            if let imgData = data {

                if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {

                    imagesMutableArray.addObject(image)

                }

                else {

                    // PUT IN "Photo Unavailable" Pic
                }
            }

            else {

                // PUT IN "Photo Unavailable" Pic
            }

        }).resume()

    }

    // UPDATE (but async op not done)
    if let downloadedImages: [UIImage] = imagesMutableArray as NSArray as? [UIImage] {

        self.images = downloadedImages

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })

    }

}
```

Problem is by the time I call for the collectionView to be reloaded, the images have not been fetched. The asynchronous operations in the for loop are certainly to blame. How to I call my `// UPDATE` code *after* the images are all downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for a series of asynchronous tasks to finish, create a `dispatch_group_t`, enter the group before starting each request, leave the group in the completion block, and then you can rely on `dispatch_group_notify` to be called when each "enter" is matched with a "leave"

```
func downloadPhotosWithURLs(urls: [String]) {
    var images = [UIImage]()

    let group = dispatch_group_create()

    for url in urls {
        dispatch_group_enter(group)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            if let imgData = data {
                if let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        images.append(image)
                    }
                } else {
                    // PUT IN "Photo Unavailable" Pic
                }
            } else {
                // PUT IN "Photo Unavailable" Pic
            }

            dispatch_group_leave(group)
        }).resume()
    }

    // UPDATE
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.images = images
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note, you really should synchronize your updates of the array of images (mutable arrays are not thread safe).

--

Having hopefully answered the question, I must confess that I would probably advise two further, yet significant changes:

1. You shouldn't hold images in an array (because if there are too many, you can run out of memory). The JPEG or PNG files might not look too large, but when the images are uncompressed in RAM, they can take a lot of memory and you can easily get memory warnings.

   You might consider downloading the images to persistent storage, not into memory. If you want to hold images in memory, use a `NSCache` for performance reasons (but purge it upon memory warning).

   If you don't have too many images, or they're all small this may not be critical. But if you're looking for a scalable solution, don't require your app to hold all of the images in an array.
2. You might not want to wait for all of the images before reloading the collection view. Generally people would advise lazy loading. So if you have 1000 images and only 20 are visible at a time, why wait for 1000 images? Focus on loading the images for the visible cells. Also, you might want to see the images pop into the collection view as they're downloaded (so rather than waiting for the first 20 visible images to be downloaded, show them as they come in).

   You generally accomplish this by having `cellForItemAtIndexPath` initiate the image download asynchronously and update the cell when it's done.